# how to hide controller name using routes when you have an id segment?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, segments

I have an url like this:

```
http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/home/categorie/11
```

to show factories in a specific category.

I want to have an url like this:

```
http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/categorie/11
```

but when i use the url routing in my config/routes file like this:

```
$route['categorie'] = 'home/categorie';
```

it does not work. am i missing something?

The working link to the page is:

```
echo '<a href="'.base_url().'home/categorie/'.$value->idcategorieen.' ">' .$value->Categorie. '</a>';
```

The link that does not work is:

```
echo '<a href="'.base_url().'categorie/'.$value->idcategorieen.' ">' .$value->Categorie. '</a>';
```

Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$route['categorie/(:num)'] = 'home/categorie/$1';
```

Here is one easy, fast and clean route :)

Please read Documantation before asking.. [CI Routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: sorry i forgot. but i tried that already but the fact was that i missed the /$1 thanks for pointing me at it :) i will accept when i'm allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to to mention the argument i.e 11 to like this

```
$route['categorie/(:num)']
```

Comment: The param is integer so its better to use :num

Comment: I gave a generic solution as question was not mentioned with type of parameter. Well you point is valid in these case.

Comment: i mentioned it.. if you look at my url it says /categorie/11. 11 is a number.